# Oracle setup with OWNER and USER fails to use one SCHEMA_VERSION table

Tags: java, oracle, flyway

We are evaluating flyway to setup an Oracle database that has an OWNER schema where all tables live, and an USER, who gets granted access to OWNER tables in the form of synonyms. Sometimes the USER needs to write their own tables, too. We'd also like to keep the upgrade sql scripts in one subdirectory, rather than having a separate directory for OWNER and USER each.

So, OWNER has the following config:

```
flyway.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521
flyway.user=OWNER
flyway.schemas=OWNER
flyway.password=OWNER
```

and USER, correspondingly

```
flyway.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521
flyway.user=USER
flyway.schemas=OWNER, USER
flyway.password=USER
```

where i would expect that flyway will access the SCHEMA_VERSION table in the OWNER schema, as it is the first one in the list of schemas.

The whole thing runs in vagrant, and when i say `vagrant up` i get an error message. The relevant snippet is:

```
==> vagrantbox: Successfully applied 1 migration to schema "OWNER" (execution time 00:00.388s).
==> vagrantbox: flyway -configFile=config/USER.conf -target=1.99999 migrate
==> vagrantbox: Flyway 3.2.1 by Boxfuse
==> vagrantbox: Database: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521 (Oracle 11.2)
==> vagrantbox: Validated 4 migrations (execution time 00:00.119s)
==> vagrantbox: Creating Metadata table: "OWNER"."schema_version"
==> vagrantbox: ERROR:
==> vagrantbox: Script failed
==> vagrantbox: -------------
==> vagrantbox: SQL State  : 42000
==> vagrantbox: Error Code : 1031
==> vagrantbox: Message    : ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
==> vagrantbox: Line       : 17
==> vagrantbox: Statement  : CREATE TABLE "OWNER"."schema_version" (
```

which looks like flyway is able to determine that the schema_version table for USER is supposed to be in the OWNER schema, but fails to see that it's already there.

In the flyway sources i see that this check is done in MetadataTableImpl like this:

```
private void createIfNotExists() {
    if (table.exists()) {
        return;
    }
```

which in turn for Oracle results in a call to the connection's metadata:

```
        resultSet = jdbcTemplate.getMetaData().getTables(
                catalog == null ? null : catalog.getName(),
                schema == null ? null : schema.getName(),
                table,
                types);
        found = resultSet.next();
```

Does this work with a stock Oracle XE version 11.2.0 JDBC driver? After adding xdb6.jar and xmlparserv2.jar from SQL Developer to the classpath the following groovy snippet

```
def results = conn.getMetaData().getTables(null, "OWNER", "schema_version")
println results.next() as boolean
```

claims otherwise:

```
$ groovy TestMetaData.groovy
false
```

That would explain that flyway seems to think the table is not there, but now i am completely stumped. What is going on here? Surely the call to getMetaData().getTables() must work in general? Or is this something the thin driver can't do?

Comment: I would not use synonyms, what does do for you?

Comment: They're convenient. OWNER has table FOO, with a view VALID_FOO. Grants USER select on VALID_FOO, and USER synonyms OWNER.VALID_FOO to USER.VALID_FOO. So USER never gets to access the raw data, and changes in validity are transparent to him. That's a common design in Oracle databases.

Comment: This can all be done according to Oracle best practice with custom roles and grants. While synonyms are convenient they cause namespace collisions.  see https://community.oracle.com/thread/984301

Comment: That's an interesting discussion, thanks. So, public synonyms are The Devil, and i can understand that.